# What happens if program creates too many threads?

Tags: multithreading, performance, threadpool

I have the following questions regarding threading:

1. If a program creates huge no. of threads, does this affect the performance of the application? And, what is the estimated cost associated with each thread?
2. Why is it important to be able to stop specific threads during their execution?
3. In Modern servers, How many threads are executed per seconds? And what is the cost?

Comment: I suspect the answer is probably in the events_params method in your controller, it seems to be referring directly to attributes of the params hash, not to the event hash within it.

Comment: Try: params.require(:manage_event).permit(... - source https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: @AJFaraday, After trying params.require(:manage_event).permit(...), I am getting an error, "param is missing or value is empty: manage_event"

Comment: @mechnicov, It looks like: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qPUK0HZk3qRdgjCFgnups2dtbuUGAPezcDJnENSL+k5S8HCNOykpsrT2IfNWW3j5Oqlv2APT5jlFwAT/my/t6Q==", "/manage_events/new"=>{"name"=>"akshay", "address"=>"haendel", "sdate"=>"2020-05-14", "edate"=>"2020-05-15", "contact"=>"1234567890", "number_of_seats"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"save"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "manage_events" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2020-05-14 23:09:20.128730"], ["updated_at", "2020-05-14 23:09:20.128730"]]
   (3.2ms)  commit transaction

Comment: "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" will help. Don't use images, include the absolutely smallest example of your code, input data, expected output and the important part of the error log. Anything beyond that wastes our time as we try to help you. Images get in the way, copy/paste the absolute minimum into the question. Don't use "edit" or "updated" tags as we can see what changed.

Comment: What does your migration look like?

Comment: @hashrocket, I don't understand your question.

Comment: If you look at the logs, you’ll see that only the date params get inserted into the db. I’m wondering if you added the extra attributes to the migration file.

Comment: @hashrocket, This is what my migration looks like:class CreateManageEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :manage_events do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :address
      t.integer :sdate
      t.integer :edate
      t.string :contact
      t.integer :number_of_seats

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

Comment: @theTinMan, Thanks for the suggestion. I will keep that in mind. However, any thoughts on my code?

Comment: When asked a question in a comment, please don't respond with data or code or significant information in another comment. Instead, edit your question and add that information into it as if the new content had been there from the start, for readability and comprehension, without using "edit" or "update" type tags as we can find what changed if necessary. Your comments above describing `Parameters` and your `migration` should be moved for instance. Comments are really for us to ask questions of you or make a suggestion that doesn't warrant writing an answer.

Comment: This helps everyone find and work from the same information. Doing otherwise forces everyone to read every comment and try to piece together when they were added and how significant your responses were, making it harder for us to help.

Answer (score 1):

Change in your `_form.html.haml`

from

```
= form_for new_manage_event_path do |f|
```

to

```
= form_for @event do |f|
```

And in controller

```
def events_params
  params.require(:manage_event).permit(:name, :address, :sdate, :edate, :contact, :number_of_seats)
end
```

Comment: Still getting empty values and console looks same as above comment.

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aHkZjGE85mCMqmqFOniPkGLz475e+CnFIxTQqzQ1Z1OGJ0PLhry5VzpMlSLGRv48RVpiBtLOUbeum93+1YhCmw==", "manage_event"=>{"name"=>"ergsf", "address"=>"vaf", "sdate"=>"2020-05-18", "edate"=>"2020-05-25", "contact"=>"fasfdaf", "number_of_seats"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"save"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "manage_events" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2020-05-14 23:33:48.723613"], ["updated_at", "2020-05-14 23:33:48.723613"]] (4.2ms)  commit transaction

Comment: database is still taking null values for the entered data

Comment: I am using rails version 4.2.10 and ruby version 2.4.0